# Basic polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have two structs:

```
struct X { double x; };

struct Y : X { double y; };
```

I want a vector filled with basic objects (of type X) which possibly can be extended (to objects of type Y):

```
    std::vector<X*> vec;

    if(condition)
    {
        for(size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            vec.push_back(new Y);
            vec[i]->x = ...;
            vec[i]->y = ...; // error
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            vec.push_back(new X);
            vec[i]->x = ...;
        }
    }
```

This gives the error " no member named 'y' in 'X' ". Do you know how I could achieve what I wish?

Comment: Polymorphism is for behaviour, usually. Looks like you need composition, maybe?

Comment: Move `double y;` from `Y` to `X`

Comment: @ Thomas Sablik That's exactly what I want to avoid: using members which are possibly not used.

Comment: Try `(dynamic_cast<Y*>(vec[i]))->y = ...;`?

Comment: @ cigien Could you explain what you mean by composition?

Comment: The immediate problem is that the code stores an `X*`. It can’t access `Y` members through that pointer. So keep the actual type: `Y* ptr = new Y; ptr->y = ...; vex.push_back(ptr);`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of inheritance here. It depends on your problem, but would `struct Y { X x_; double y; };` work?

Comment: @AdrianMole — `dynamic_cast` won’t work unless the base type has one or more virtual functions.

Comment: @PeteBecker Fair comment! Would `static_cast` do the trick in this case? I see your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011553/10871073) addresses this issue.

Comment: Dou you want to put either X or Y in the vector or can the vector also be filled with a mixture?

Comment: @ Sebastian Either X or Y.

Comment: @AdrianMole — yes `static_cast` would work **if you know** that the `X*` in fact points at an object of type `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution for the code you posted so far. Change

```
vec.push_back(new Y);
vec[i]->x = ...;
vec[i]->y = ...; // error
```

to

```
Y* newy = new Y;
vec.push_back(newy);
newy->x = ...;
newy->y = ...; // no error
```

But then you will still need a cast of X* to Y* when reading the object back to access the member variables only contained in Y.

```
if(condition)
    cout << static_cast<Y*>(vec[i])->y;
```

Instead of casts you could also create separate vectors for X and Y (do not need to be pointers, if they contain only the one type, but could also be the pointers) and just fill and access one of them.

```
vector<X> vecX;
vector<Y> vecY;
bool condition;
```